# DATEDIFF in YII MYSQL

Tags: mysql, yii, criteria, datediff

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition(array('where' => 'select DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),t.due_date) < 0'));
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Loan', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
));
$this->render('index', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
```

This is my code, I want to retreive all data from 'Loan' model with some criteria, but I found problem like so:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION libraryng.DATEDIFF does not exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `loans` `t` WHERE (select DATEFIFF(CURDATE(),t.due_date) < 0)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [*YII: Date compare in CDBCriteria*](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22378-date-compare-in-cdbcriteria-solved/) - should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

change this line to

```
$criteria->condition('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),`t`.due_date) < 0');
```